# Keep rows only if contains certain value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data:

```
   item  colour machine
0   car     red       a
1   car     red       b
2   car   green       b
3   car    blue       a
4  moto  yellow       a
5  moto     red       a
6  bike    blue       a
7  bike    blue       b
8  bike   green       a
```

And I'm trying to keep only the items that have a record on the machine a and b. I tried some functions I found on the internet, but it doesn't work, so I got to do it with `data.drop()` by hand. Does it exist some function to do that work? The resulting `dataframe` should be:

```
   item colour machine
0   car    red       a
1   car    red       b
2  bike   blue       a
3  bike   blue       b
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with custom lambda function for compare values converted to `tuple`, `list` and then filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

Also if necessary not sure if order is always `a,b` first sorting:

```
df = df.sort_values(['item','colour','machine'])

f = lambda x: tuple(x) == tuple(['a','b'])
#alternative
f = lambda x: list(x) == list(['a','b'])
#solution if want compare and remove duplicates
#f = lambda x: set(x) == set(['a','b'])
df = df[df.groupby(['item','colour'])['machine'].transform(f)]

print (df)
   item colour machine
0   car    red       a
1   car    red       b
6  bike   blue       a
7  bike   blue       b
```